# Mock a different window.location in puppeteer

Tags: jestjs, puppeteer

Is there a way to tell puppeteer to use a different url when referencing `window.location` etc?

I am running screenshot tests using jest-storyshots-puppeteer and there are some places where the current url is printed to the screen (not my design haha), so the test returns differently depending on where they are run (ie localhost vs ciserver vs dist etc). I'd like to

I was digging through the methods available on the `page` object (i am already injecting some CSS to remove transitions and hide images), but don't see any way to achieve this.

```
const beforeScreenshot = (page, { context: { kind, story }, url }) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    if (envConfig.includeOverrideStyles) {
      page.addStyleTag({
        content: overrideStyles
      });
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
    }, envConfig.timeout);
  });
};
```

Comment: I believe you won't be able to change that. The only solution coming to my mind is overriding the location property. But we can't override that prop.

Comment: @hardkoded cool.. I suppose I could create my own function in my own code and override it via puppeteer... but that doesn't feel like a good practice. i will just use custom css hide the offending elements for now

Comment: I tried overriding window.location but it's not allowed